# <div> блок с текстом по середине и плюсом "fa fa-plus" справа

Tags: html, css

Как видите текст не по центру, нужна помощь. Из-за "плюса" текст съезжает левее.

[image: Хочу сделать вот такой блок, где текст будет по середине, а справа "fa fa-plus"]

Comment: сделайте у текста `margin-right: -ширина плюса`

Comment: @azlov, отрицательные margin'ы плохая практика. В данном случае, лучше использовать padding-left ранвый ширине FA иконки.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.elem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: #857bfe;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.elem > span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="elem">
  <span>Название колонки</span>
  <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Иконке плюс присвойте `position: absolute`, тексту установите отступы по бокам соответсвующие размеру иконки, чтобы при изменении размера кнопки не наложились друг на друга.

Comment: Всё это находится внутри <div class="text-center col-md-6">, если я задам position: absolute, то плюс переедет в центр, к тексту.

Comment: Ну тогда приложите код, я же не знаю, что у вас там где

Comment: @XeroxLaser у этого дива который вы приводите в комментарии, укажите класс position-relative и тогда никуда не уедет ничего